# Undo all appended HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code. It adds and alters the HTML, when the user is looking in a smaller window:

```
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');
            $('.col45').insertAfter('.col55');
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');

            $('<span class="slide-left"></span>' + '<span class="slide-right"></span>').appendTo('.main-slide');

        } else {

            //    REVERT BACK TO NORMAL   
        };
```

However, when the user then expands the window, the changes are left on the screen. What would be the best way to undo what has just been done? I'm aware I can use `$(window).resize()`, but I'm not sure how to revert the changes?

Any help or guidance would be great.

Comment: I suppose you have to remove all the things you added.

Comment: It seems these elements may be on the page and possibly hidden. I would use a unique class to identify these element (when they are added) and just remove all elements with the class name.

Comment: I would look into CSS Media queries if I were you. That way you won't have to worry about the logic as much. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Why do you use js for this task? It can be done with help css media queries only

Comment: May I suggest using css and media queries instead...? -Seems all you're doing is showing or hiding content anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but some of these ie insertAfter I'm changing the order of the DOM

Comment: I think your headline is putting everyone (myself included) off... You are moving existing DOM elements, as well as appending new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would do none of that. I'd include those elements in the page at all times, with a class like 'narrow' added to all of the smaller-window-only elements. Then, in my CSS:

```css
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .narrow {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

To hide them in wider windows.

Comment: I guess I will have to do this. I was trying not to repeat the HTML on the same page, but this would probably be just as fast as adding it anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Insert this code in your else condition

```
    $('.slideshow-float-right").next('.btn-ar.view-gallery').remove();
    $('.col55').next('.col45').remove();
    $('.main-slide').find('.slide-left').remove();
    $('.main-slide').find('.slide-right').remove();
```

Else

When you add the elements, to those elements add an unique class for example `smallScreen`

then in the else condition:

```
if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');
            $('.col45').insertAfter('.col55');
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');

            $('<span class="slide-left"></span>' + '<span class="slide-right"></span>').appendTo('.main-slide');

        } else {
               $(".smallScreen").remove();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .you have to store all class in one array. here i have stored example class ..u need store which is append class

```
 var addedClass = new Array('btn-ar.view-gallery', 'col45', 'btn-ar.view-gallery', 'slide-right');


        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');
            $('.col45').insertAfter('.col55');
            $('.btn-ar.view-gallery').insertAfter('.slideshow-float-right');

            $('<span class="slide-left"></span>' + '<span class="slide-right"></span>').appendTo('.main-slide');

        } else {

            for (var i in addedClass) {
                $("." + addedClass[i]).remove();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no magic way to revert changes made to the order of DOM elements (since page load I assume), as their original position isn't stored...

You could store each elements original position manually, or try this for an easy fix:

```
var original_html = '';

if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    if (!original_html)
        original_html = $("body").html();
    //Do your manipulation
} else {
    //Restore everything
    if (original_html)
        $("body").html(original_html);
};
```